# Lightweight command-line client?

Tags: client

I need to be able to generate addresses and receive bitcoins to them, then send them somewhere else - and do it on a server via some command-line interface. Is it possible to do so without downloading the whole blockchain, as bitcoind requires? That is, is there a lightweight client, but for the command line?

Comment: I think your real question is that you want to write a program that can detect when it receives bitcoins. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Electrum has a text-only version, although I found I had to set it up first time using the gui. Here's my write-up on running it on a Raspberry Pi via SSH though, which sounds like it might do what you need:

http://bitcoinlife.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/running-electrum-on-a-raspberry-pi/